# Proving $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $f(x) = |x|x$ is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $f(x) = |x|x$, I am trying to prove that $f$ is smooth.

So far, I took its partial derivatives, all of which are polynomials. I know that polynomials are continuous and, intuitively, it must be   case that they are smooth, and if all the components are smooth, the function is smooth. I've only proved that a function is differentiable if its components are differentiable, but not smoothness. I assume it also holds, but I don't know how to prove it. Is induction it?

Comment: hey Stanley, I saw that you have not accepted any answers to your prior questions. If you agree with the answers given, you should click on the tick ✔️ to the left of the answer, under the up/downvote arrows to mark it as Accepted, so that other people know that the question has been resolved. (And if you don't agree with the answers, please try to discuss it with the answerer!)

Answer (score 2):

If it was smooth, its first component $f_1(x)=|x|x_1$ would be smooth when its domain was restricted to the line $$\{ (t,0,\dots,0): t\in\mathbb R\}$$
and on this line, $f_1((t,0,\dots,0)) = g(t):= |t|t$. But $g$ is not smooth; $g$ is merely once differentiable at $t=0$. Indeed,
$$ g(t)=\begin{cases}t^2 & t\ge 0, \\ -t^2 & t< 0\end{cases}$$
so (and one checks $t=0$ carefully)
$$ g'(t)=\begin{cases}2t & t\ge 0, \\ -2t & t< 0\end{cases} = 2|t| $$
and $|t|$ is not differentiable at $t=0$. (But $|t|$ is continuous, so $g$ belongs to the slightly better space $C^1(\mathbb R)$.)

We see a posteriori that the partials are not polynomials. (In fact, the above is an explicit calculation of a partial.) However, if you consider restricting the domain to a set that avoids the origin, then $f$ is indeed smooth.

Comment: Because the derivative is continuous, the function $t \mapsto |t| t$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, which is a bit more regular than just once differentiable.

Comment: @JoelCohen indeed, my "merely" was meant to say "as opposed to twice or thrice differentiable", but then I lost a part saying $C^1$. I'll word $C^1$ into the answer in a moment...thanks